# combining Greasing the Groove with regular strength workout

Tags: workout-routines, strength, push-ups, pull-ups

So I am interested in using Greasing the Groove(GtG) to increase my number of pullups and pushups. I am a beginner at strength training, so I figured I would post my question here.  My goal is more to increase strength rather than going for muscle size. I am trying to figure out how to balance GtG with regular strength workouts. In other words, If I continue doing strength training 3 days a week, would I just add short GtG sessions throughout the day on both workout days and rest days? Also, can I exercise the same muscles in my GtG sessions as in my full body workout sessions? In other words, if I do GtG pullups throughout the day or week, can I still do back rows or similar exercises during my regular workout sessions?

Of course I dont' want to overtrain. I figure it might just be a process of trial and error to see what works for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

John Scheaffer, in his e-book "The Greyskull LP," suggests that frequency method bodyweight exercise can be added to a linear progression (LP) with good result. Most importantly, the higher volume of bodyweight exercise can help with upper body hypertrophy.

Scheaffer suggests never getting close to failure on frequency method bodyweight exercise. For example, if you can do seven good pull-ups, do six sets of four throughout the day. These are to be done every day, with one rest day per week. That should answer your first question.

To answer your second question, frequency method exercises are supplementary to your lifting program. In "The Greyskull LP," they are add-ins to the barbell-focused LP.

Comment: If the OP wants to emphasize strength over size, why recommend something that "helps with upper body hypertrophy"?

Comment: Maybe I should have presented that information differently. Regardless, OP wants to do it; I'm not recommending anything.